# Why is Shopify Theme Dynamic Subtotal Javascript is being blocked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I'm having an issue with a dynamic subtotal on this [page](https://ropecentral.com.au/collections/marine-ropes/products/synthetic-braid) made on the shopify theme "Kalles" by the4 - it uses a custom Js function called
`$(document).on('variant:changed', function (evt) {});` to update the subtotal when another variant is choosen on the page.

[image: Dynamic subtotal location]

This function is being stopped by something but I can't workout what it is - all I can see in console is an error. [image: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'min')]

I have installed this on other sites with the same shopify theme and it works fine without issue [eg](https://haverford.com.au/collections/featured-range/products/by-the-metre-40mm-sq-36ply-2-0mm-diameter?variant=12702347952241)

I currently have this script running on the site but as you can see the subtotal isn't working and keeps the first load variant price only as the script is being blocked.

```
$(document).on('variant:changed', function (evt) {
        const qty_input = $('.t4s-quantity-input'),
          pr_container = $('.t4s-product__info-container'),
          total_wrapper = $('.t4s-form__product .product-form__sub-total');
        const variant = evt.currentVariant;
        if (qty_input && total_wrapper && variant) {
          var price = variant.price;
          total_wrapper.attr('data-price', price);

          const total = T4SThemeSP.Currency.formatMoney(parseInt(qty_input.val()) * price);

          total_wrapper.find('.t4s-product-price').html(total);
        }
        if (pr_container) {
          if (!variant.available && variant.price == 0) {
            pr_container.addClass('t4s-product__info-out');
          } else {
            pr_container.removeClass('t4s-product__info-out');
          }
        }
      });

      function changeQty() {
        const qty_input = $('.t4s-quantity-input'),
          total_wrapper = $('.t4s-form__product .product-form__sub-total');
        if (qty_input && total_wrapper) {
          qty_input.on('change', function (e) {
            var price = total_wrapper[0].dataset.price;
            var currentqty = qty_input.val();
            const total = T4SThemeSP.Currency.formatMoney(parseInt(this.value) * price);
            total_wrapper.find('.t4s-product-price').html(total);
            $('.t4s-sticky-atc__price').html(total);
          });
        }
      }
      changeQty();
```

I've tried predefining min & max without any luck - also I have brought it into a clean instance of shopify and it works fine. Which leads me to believe that the script is being blocked by one of the applications.

Would it be best to script something from scratch to not rely on the theme or did someone know why the script would be producing an error?

I have left comments in the html to make it easy to find on the site ""

Comment: it seem the store is offering B2B, and need some additional setup on variant level to avoid these JS errors.

Comment: Thank you for the help Onkar! Would you happen to know where the documentation was for the additional setup?

Comment: Actually after investigation @Onkar ! I don't think that is the reason - I have another site using [b2b](https://gutzbusta.com.au/collections/top-picks/products/knotless-hay-nets-small?variant=47076116463921) and as you can see it is working fine.

Was there some additional b2b setting that might be causing the other sites issues?

Comment: Are you able to share the URL of the B2B on which it working fine

Comment: @Onkar - [Here](https://haverford.com.au/collections/featured-range/products/ball-stop-barrier-nets-with-support-posts-40mm-sq-multiple-sizes?variant=40184257249393)

Comment: Here you can check the  quantity_rule is exists into product variant where it works. https://prnt.sc/Q-UVPHUJZBkg

Comment: Here is it missing and generates the related issue, and does not works https://prnt.sc/Ac5ag5ZqknuQ

Comment: The solution is to add the property into the backend so the code works well or update the code to check if it exists or not then skip the code.

Comment: @Onkar Thank you for the insight! I really appreciate the help. I checked through the code is it is calling this liquid code ```{{ product.variants | json }}```

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://shopify.dev/docs/api/liquid/objects/quantity_rule) the quantity_rule should be included in this liquid call. However it isn't appearing - was there an additional setting that needs to be turned on for shopify to output this?

Comment: I think you need to check this [guide](https://help.shopify.com/en/manual/b2b/catalogs/quantity-pricing#quantity-rules). how to add pricing rule for B2B store.